# Appropiate intent flags Android for background tasks?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-intent

I am working in an Android project. I have 3 Activities (Home, Loading, Menu). The first activty (Home) calls in a background task (when the server answers) to "Menu Activity", but, meanwhile the "Loading" Activity is called for displaying feedback to user. My problem is that when I am in the Menu Activity and I press the back botton, the app shows the Loading activity, and it is wrong. I have been testing different flags, but I have not get the solution.
Can anyone help me, please ?

Comment: Sounds like a good candidate for fragments. Wonder why you don't use fragments.

Comment: How would it be with fragments? Thank you @The_Martian